# cannot access private member declared in class 'Soldier'

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, private

I'm new to OOP and I do not understand how to pass arguments to classes.

The class' declaration:

```
class Soldier
{
    Soldier(int SetHealth, int SetStrength);

private:
    int health;
    int strength;

public:
    void attacked();
    void healed();
    int getHealth();
    int getStrength();
};
```

Definition of the constructor:

```
    Soldier::Soldier(int SetHealth, int SetStrength):
        health(SetHealth),
        strength(SetStrength)
    {

    }
```

When I try passing arguments to the class it says this:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication6, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>  ConsoleApplication6.cpp
    1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6.cpp(11): error C2248: 'Soldier::Soldier' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Soldier'
    1>          c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\soldier.h(7) : see declaration of 'Soldier::Soldier'
    1>          c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\soldier.h(6) : see declaration of 'Soldier'
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `class` default access specifier is `privare`. `struct` is `public`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

People have already answered this now, but explicitly:

```
class Soldier
{
private:
    int health;
    int strength;

public:
    Soldier(int SetHealth, int SetStrength);

    void attacked();
    void healed();
    int getHealth();
    int getStrength();
};
```

BTW What are attached and healed going to do? They take no parameters and return nothing. Odd.

Moving the constructor to the public "section", makes it `public`. Things start off as `private` until you say otherwise.

Comment: My guess is they'll increment or decrement `health` internally.

Comment: Or print it, or zero it, ... ;-)

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the solution in any way.

Answer (score 6):

Your constructor is `private` (just as the error message says).
By default, every member of a `Class` is `private` if you don't specify an access level.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor that you have defined has a access level of

```
private
```

By default if one does not mention anything, the access level is private
So change it to public for access.

Answer (score 1):

A class's members are implicitly `private` unless you change the access level to `public` or `protected`, so `Soldier::Soldier(int SetHealth, int SetStrength);` is private - ergo you can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

changet constructor declaration to this `public Soldier(int SetHealth, int SetStrength);`

Comment: That's C# - you need a colon